# how to enable bluetooth and change brightness in sony vaio VPCEH26EN?

Tags: bluetooth, brightness

There are two basic questions. i have vpceh26en sony vaio laptop. i'm using ubuntu 12.04 32 bit as my sole OS. Neither bluetooth is working(says its disabled) nor the brightness can be changed using the slider.

P.S : my system is 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

When you open Ubuntu 12.04 just connect your system to internet and open Additional Drivers application........And it shows graphics driver for your system......From there you can install those drivers and after that you have chance of decreasing brightness.....

I am using VAIO E-Series lapi and I am also having the problem of Bluetooth.....